# How to get phsical address of a shared memory

Tags: linux, shared-memory

The following source create a shared memory in /dev/shm

```
static char* conf;
#define STATE_FILE "/memtest.shared"

int shm_fd;
if((shm_fd = shm_open(STATE_FILE, (O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR),
                   (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) > 0 ) {
    ; /* We are the first instance */
}
else if((shm_fd = shm_open(STATE_FILE, (O_CREAT | O_RDWR),
                    (S_IREAD | S_IWRITE))) < 0)
{
    printf("Could not create shm object. %s\n", strerror(errno));
    exit( 0 ) ;
}
int iTotalByte = 1024*1024*2 ;
ftruncate(shm_fd, iTotalByte );
conf =  (char *) mmap(0, iTotalByte , (PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0) ;
if(conf  == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf(" mmap error ....\n")  ;
    exit( 0 ) ;
}
```

Then I run the application  to  attach the shared memory :

```
numactl -N 0 -m 0 ./testz.exe <== pid 19852
```

I try to figure out in /proc/19852/maps  or pmap -XX 19852
what is phsical address of /dev/shm/memtest.shared 
and failed to interpret, I observe INode is the same for every application attach memtest.shared but don't know if this is the physical address of memtest.shared , how to get a shared memory's phsical address ?!

Notes :

What I try to do is that suppose shared memory's physical address is 0x700000 , then I can access it using mmap /dev/mem ,offset 0x700000 and read the contents , that is why I like to know the shared memory's physical address.

Comment: Unless you lock it into memory, the physical address can change.

Comment: And if the memory is larger than one memory page, the physical addresses might not be contiguous. Shared memory is virtual memory.

Comment: @Barmar , what if  I change my test shared memory size less than one page ?!  Can I have the chance to get a exist shared memory's physical address ?!  and how to get it ?!

Comment: AFAIK there's no standard API to translate virtual addresses into physical addresses. You'd need to read the page table data structure in the kernel.

Comment: @Barmar , thanks for your kind reply .